# IP Switch ws_ftp script to delete all files from directory after xfer

Tags: batch-file, ftp, batch-processing

I have the following script that I thought would delete all the xfered files from my local dir but it's actually delete all the files from the other dir.

`CONNECT ARx
ONERROR GOTO ERROR
LCD "C:\FTP Folders\ARx\ARxScanning"
ONSUCCESS GOTO FILEDELETE
MPUT *.PDF
LABEL FILEDELETE
MDELETE *
LABEL ERROR
CLOSE`

How do I delete all files from the local dir? I can't use PXDELETE because I want to delete all files weather they were transferred or not.

Comment: Don't you use the `!<command>` symbol to run commands on your local machine in FTP? Maybe try something like `!del *.pdf`

Comment: More detail: I'm using the task manager on the ftp server to run the .scp which is the script above. Are suggesting deleting the files in the task manager instead of putting it in .scp file?

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to run the script from your local machine?